# How to render an image in shiny box and fix the width and height? R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have this shiny app I am making. My goal is to have a fluid row that has an image and some inputs

```
# Test Version with google logo

library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashbaord"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "Image Goes Here",
        img(src='https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/ULiGDiA4_u4SaK-xexvmJVYUNY0=/0x0:640x427/1400x1050/filters:focal(0x0:640x427):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/assets/3218223/google.jpg',
            align = "center",
            width = "100%",
            style="height: 50px")), #I'm trying to change the size here but it doesn't work
      box(align = "center",
        title = "Select Inputs",status = "warning", solidHeader = F,
        selectInput("dropdown1", "Select Drilldown:", c(50,100,200))
    )
        
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Technically this code works, but I don't like how the box with the image changes based off the monitor/view. I would like for both boxes to be the same height and remain uniformed. I posted some screen shots below.

Full Screen
[image]

Half Screen
[image]

Desire Output (row is the same height no matter what).
[image]

Edit:

```
box_height = "20em"
plot_height = "16em"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Box alignmnent test"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Put boxes in a row
    fluidRow(
      box(
        title = "Image Goes Here",
        img(src='https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/ULiGDiA4_u4SaK-xexvmJVYUNY0=/0x0:640x427/1400x1050/filters:focal(0x0:640x427):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/assets/3218223/google.jpg',
            align = "center",
            width = "100%"),
              height = box_height),
         
            
       box(plotOutput("speed_distbn",height = plot_height), height = box_height)
        )
      )
    )
  


server <- function(input, output) {

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Boxes stay the same height but the image overlaps the box
[image]

Comment: You have "height" spelled wrong  in your style line, perhaps that helps to solve the issue?

Comment: Okay, I corrected that but now it makes the image pixilated and look bad. And the size is still not the same.

Comment: I noticed ```box()``` has a height argument, if you set both boxes height to say ```box(height = "200px")```, does that work to keep them the height you want?

Comment: So I did that and the boxes stay the same size but the image actually just renders on top/over it. Let me show you in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

my_height = "30em"

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Box alignmnent test"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        # Put boxes in a row
        fluidRow(
            box(
                title = "Image Goes Here",
                img(src='https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/ULiGDiA4_u4SaK-xexvmJVYUNY0=/0x0:640x427/1400x1050/filters:focal(0x0:640x427):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/assets/3218223/google.jpg',
                    align = "center", style = paste0("width: 100%; height: ", my_height, ";"))
            ),
            box(title = "Plot", plotOutput("speed_distbn", height = my_height))
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    output$speed_distbn <- renderPlot(plot(1))
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

In your first case, if you want to use other random tags on the right side. In order to have the right the same height as left, we can use `spsComps::heightMatcher`. We can use this function to dynamically match the height of the right side to the left side.

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

my_height = "30em"

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Box alignmnent test"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
        # Put boxes in a row
        fluidRow(
            box(
                title = "Image Goes Here",
                id= "box_l",
                img(src='https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/ULiGDiA4_u4SaK-xexvmJVYUNY0=/0x0:640x427/1400x1050/filters:focal(0x0:640x427):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/assets/3218223/google.jpg',
                    align = "center", style = paste0("width: 100%; height: ", my_height, ";"))
            ),
            box(
                title = "Select inputs", 
                id= "box_r",
                selectInput("dropdown1", "Select Drilldown:", c(50,100,200))
            ),
            spsComps::heightMatcher("box_r", "box_l")
        )
    )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

In your case, the height on left is fixed, but `heightMatcher` can do it even with dynamically changed height. try click on [spsComps shiny demo](https://github.com/lz100/spsComps#demos) and go to the *Misc* tab and see the dynamic `heightMatcher` example.